# Migrating jupyter notebook to .py file (spyder) basic plotting is killed by latex

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, jupyter-notebook, spyder

Hello stackoverflow community,

I am using Anaconda with python 3.5 on a mac with os sierra. I have an extensive script with several plot commands from matplotlib. Which works fine, even when I plot over 1000 figures. I wanted to download the notebook to use it in spyder as .py script.

I am fairly sure, that it does not contain errors, and it works properly if I run it in the jupyter notebook. But with spyder I get a bunch of error messages:

```
runfile('/Users/user/imb-buoy-scripts/ProblemsWithPlotting.py',wdir='
/Users/user/imb-buoy-scripts')
<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x11f5836a0>
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython
/core/formatters.py", line 339, in __call__
return printer(obj)

File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython
/core/pylabtools.py", line 228, in <lambda>
png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png',
**kwargs))

File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython
/core/pylabtools.py", line 119, in print_figure
fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)

File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib
/backend_bases.py", line 2180, in print_figure
**kwargs)

File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib
/backends/backend_agg.py", line 527, in print_png
FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)

File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib
/backends/backend_agg.py", line 474, in draw
self.figure.draw(self.renderer)

File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib
/artist.py", line 61, in draw_wrapper
draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib
/figure.py", line 1159, in draw
func(*args)

File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib
/artist.py", line 61, in draw_wrapper
draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib
/axes/_base.py", line 2324, in draw
a.draw(renderer)

File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib
/artist.py", line 61, in draw_wrapper
draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib
/axis.py", line 1108, in draw
renderer)

File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib
/axis.py", line 1058, in _get_tick_bboxes
extent = tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)

File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib
/text.py", line 961, in get_window_extent
bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)

File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib
/text.py", line 352, in _get_layout
ismath=False)

File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib
/backends/backend_agg.py", line 229, in get_text_width_height_descent
renderer=self)

File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib
/texmanager.py", line 678, in get_text_width_height_descent
page = next(iter(dvi))

File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib
/dviread.py", line 89, in __iter__
have_page = self._read()

File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib
/dviread.py", line 150, in _read
self._dispatch(byte)

File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib
/dviread.py", line 233, in _dispatch
self._fnt_def(k, c, s, d, a, l, n)

File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib
/dviread.py", line 388, in _fnt_def
tfm = _tfmfile(fontname)

File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib
/dviread.py", line 897, in _tfmfile
return _fontfile(texname, Tfm, '.tfm', _tfmcache)

File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib
/dviread.py", line 887, in _fontfile
filename = find_tex_file(texname + suffix)

File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib
/dviread.py", line 868, in find_tex_file
stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 950, 
in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)

File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1544, 
in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'kpsewhich'
```

I would be very grateful, if someone could help me or point me in the right direction.

Thanks for your attention :)

So edit: 
The reason is in the definition of the fonts I use for matplotlib:
This is the example code:

```
# coding: utf-8
# # Problems with plots after migrating from .ipynb to .py

# In[2]:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gs

from matplotlib import rc # this is the matplotlib suggestion
rc('font',**{'family':'sans-serif','sans-serif':['Helvetica']})
rc('text', usetex=True)

# In[3]:
mat = np.random.rand(5,5)

# In[4]:
fig = plt.figure()
gsall = gs.GridSpec(6, 1)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gsall[:])
source1 = ax1.contourf(mat,extend='both',cmap=mpl.cm.viridis)
plt.title('Random field \n test')
plt.colorbar(source1)

# In[5]:
plt.show()
```

so if i comment the rc('text') I get this new error messages, which I was told had to do with matplotlib. just setting it to 'Arial' instead of 'Helvetica' cures the problem.

```
/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib
/font_manager.py:1288: UserWarning: findfont: Font family 
['sans-serif'] not found. Falling back to Bitstream Vera Sans
(prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))
```

the above mentioned error is created by this guy, concerning the use of latex in matplotlib:

```
rc('text', usetex=True)
```

http://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html what I had in the code was precisely the example from matplotlib.

Answer (score 1):

incorrectly used plt instead of your instance of plt, "fig" in In[4] and In[5]

```
def plot_tst():
    '''

    '''
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib as mpl
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.gridspec as gs

    mat = np.random.rand(5,5)

    fig = plt.figure()
    gsall = gs.GridSpec(6, 1)
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gsall[:])
    source1 = ax1.contourf(mat,extend='both',cmap=mpl.cm.viridis)
    fig.suptitle('Random field \n test')
    fig.colorbar(source1)

plot_tst()
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GCrv.png

I also changed title() to suptitle() but really don't understand why title() isn't working
but there is commentary on Windows and Spyder ipython console graphics issues

(I'm running Spyder 2.39 on Win 7, Spyder does have a 3.0.1 release now)

Comment: thank you, this helps with the example, but I still get an error with the extensive script... have a nice evening and thank you!

Comment: what is needed to mark this as answered?  does my last edit help?

Comment: it helped with the example, but this solution had no effect on the 'real script' which causes the problem in the first place. Also the real script works perfectly in jupyter while causing the problem in spyder, therefore I think it is not a syntax problem. So your answer still does not help me. I am sorry, but I can not mark your suggestion as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce [this example](http://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html) without problems over Ipython console.

[Screenshot of my Spyder test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGQ7w.png)

only need

- Latest version of spyder (3.0.1)
- sudo apt-get install dvipng (library for manage latex character conversion on matplotlib)

I hope this help you.